Ring through a tube electrical symbol - what is it?
What component or action does the tube with a ring through it refer to?
I believe the switch it's attached to is the low side switch of the Analog Devices ADP5090 regulator and they do say that the chip has circuitry to limit the current flow through the low side switch. Elsewhere in the datasheet the switch is drawn directly connected to input.




Image is part of the "Detailed Functional Block Diagram" in the ADP5090 datasheet




Image is the "Power Switches Structure" in the ADP5090 datasheet

The short answer is that it's some kind of (probably considered 'lossless') current measurement structure so that an external (or internal) shunt resistor is not required to know the inductor current.
We've done this before, for another similar chip, and there was no satisfactory answer as to what, exactly, the symbol is referencing that time either.
The datasheet contains this phrase:

To maintain the high efficiency of the regulator across a wide input
power range, the current sense circuitry employs the internal dither
peak current limit to control the inductor current.

P.S. I've asked the question in the AD forums. Will amend this answer if any clues are forthcoming from the good folks in Wilmington.

It's certainly an odd way to draw it. Normally, current sensing in an IC is done by diverting some fraction of the drain current (controlled by relative contact area) to a separate terminal.
